# PHP can't get cookie that was set in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies

I am using PHP 8.0 and this is a wordpress site version 6.1.1

I have a plugin that is setting a cookie like so:

```
window.tourmaster_set_cookie = function( cname, cvalue, expires ){
        if( typeof(expires) != 'undefined' ){
            if( expires == 0 ){
                expires = 86400;
            }

            var now = new Date();
            var new_time  = now.getTime() + (parseInt(expires) * 1000);
            now.setTime(new_time);

            expires = now.toGMTString();
        }

        document.cookie = cname + "=" + encodeURIComponent(cvalue) + "; expires=" + expires + "; path=/";
    }
```

This is being called like so:

```
tourmaster_set_cookie('tourmaster-room-cart', JSON.stringify(cart_cookie), 31536000);
```

I can see in my console log that this cookie is being set.

However when I try to get the cookie in PHP:

```
$_COOKIE['tourmaster-room-cart']
```

I get this error:

> Warning: Undefined array key "tourmaster-room-cart"

When I do a print_r on `$_COOKIE` the cookie "tourmaster-room-cart" is not there.

What is going wrong here and how can I fix it?

**UPDATE**

I created this simple cookie:

```
document.cookie = "username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2025 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
```

and it appears in my php `$_COOKIE`;

However this does not show up in `$_COOKIE`

```
window.tourmaster_set_cookie = function( cname, cvalue, expires ){
        expires = "Thu, 1 Jan 2026 12:00:00 UTC";
        if( typeof(expires) != 'undefined' ){
            if( expires == 0 ){
                expires = 86400;
            }

            var now = new Date();
            var new_time  = now.getTime() + (parseInt(expires) * 1000);
            now.setTime(new_time);

            expires = now.toGMTString();
        }

        document.cookie = cname + "=test; expires=Thu, 1 Jan 2026 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";

    }
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

I added a few more cookies to see if they would get displayed with $_COOKIES, they all did except for the last test with encodeURIComponent(cvalue) as the value. It must be something in my value? Here is the updated code and below that is the value.

```
window.tourmaster_set_cookie = function( cname, cvalue, expires ){
        if( typeof(expires) != 'undefined' ){
            if( expires == 0 ){
                expires = 86400;
            }

            var now = new Date();
            var new_time  = now.getTime() + (parseInt(expires) * 1000);
            now.setTime(new_time);

            expires = now.toGMTString();
        }
        document.cookie = "newusernameagain=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2025 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
        document.cookie = "newusername-again=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2025 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
        document.cookie = "new-username-again=" + encodeURIComponent(cvalue) + "; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2025 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + encodeURIComponent(cvalue) + "; expires=" + expires + "; path=/";

    }
```

And the value

> %5B%7B%22start_date%22%3A%222023-02-05%22%2C%22end_date%22%3A%222023-02-06%22%2C%22room_amount%22%3A%221%22%2C%22adult%22%3A%5B%222%22%5D%2C%22children%22%3A%5B%220%22%5D%2C%22room_id%22%3A%2215701%22%2C%22post_type%22%3A%22room%22%7D%5D

I have no idea what is going wrong.

**FINAL UPDATE**

For some stupid reason when I remove the dashes from the cookie name and where it is referenced everything works. For some odd reason $_COOKIE does not like dashes for the cookie name on this godaddy server, very odd stuff.

Comment: Can you successfully read the cookie value in JavaScript, e.g. `console.log(document.cookie);`? You might troubleshoot possible problems with expiration or path.

Comment: How can I tell? cookies is not my speciality

Comment: I wonder if it's an [issue with WordPress caching](https://wpengine.com/support/cookies-and-php-sessions/#Issues_with_Cookies): "A cookie may only work as expected when you are logged in to the WordPress Admin Dashboard. This is because logged-in user sessions specifically bypass the page cache layer and will be processed by PHP every time."

Comment: Hi, yes the cookies does exists when I do: console.log(document.cookie);

Comment: Where and when are you trying to read the cookie in PHP?

Comment: Your logic for handling the `expires`-date has some big issues. You pass it in as a string, but use it as an integer (using `parseInt(expires)` for example). You only give `expires` a default value if the value already is defined and equals to `0`. If it's not defined (like if it isn't passed at all), then `expires` will be undefined.

Comment: Steps to debug this: look in the storage/application inspector to see what cookies are set for the site. Then look in the Network tab to see if they’re sent in the request headers. Depending on the results of this, go from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have passed a correct value (e.g. "SO test") in `cart_cookie`, then the script should work.

A normal way to set cookie in JS is like:

```
document.cookie = "username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 1 Jan 2016 12:00:00 UTC";
```

So assuming the JS script is:

```
<script>
window.tourmaster_set_cookie = function( cname, cvalue, expires ){
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + encodeURIComponent(cvalue) + "; expires=" + expires + "; path=/";
    }

tourmaster_set_cookie('tourmaster-room-cart', JSON.stringify('SO test'), "Thu, 1 Jan 2026 12:00:00 UTC");

alert("Done ! Now redirecting to show the cookie string");

window.location.href="testSO5Feb2023c.php"; 

</script>
```

On running it , it will set the cookie, and then redirect to another page (I named it testSO5Feb2023c.php), which shows that the cookie is correctly set

For testSO5Feb2023c.php :

```
<?php

echo "Cookie is now : <br>";
echo $_COOKIE['tourmaster-room-cart']; 

?>
```

You may see the [DEMO](http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/testSO5Feb2023b.php)

Last but not least, please note that `the cookie is retrievable ONLY after it is set`, so make sure the page to display the cookie is different from the one you set the cookie, otherwise you may need a page refresh

Comment: Have a look at how the `expires`-date actually is handled and you'll see some more issues (the function seem to expect a timestamp, not a date string, it only sets a default if a date is passed and equals to `0` etc).

Answer (score 0):

For some stupid reason when I remove the dashes from the cookie name and where it is referenced everything works. For some odd reason `$_COOKIE` does not like dashes for the cookie name on this godaddy server, very odd stuff.

Comment: That's good to know and a quick Google search indicates that your server issue may be due Nginx not supporting cookie names with dashes.  This would be a much better answer if you did a bit more research to confirm this is in fact your issue and then provide some supporting documentation for the benefit of future readers.